# How to uninstall cairo 0 from Mac after update to Cairo 1?

Tags: blockchain, starknet, cairo-lang

I am trying to remove Cairo 1 and all the files installed through `protostar`.

I have already built Cairo 1 and added it to the PATH of my Mac, everything is working fine but sometimes I am getting conflict with old executables.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
rm -rf ~/.protostar/
```